# Maintaining Seperate Dev/Prod Config files on Heroku doesn't work

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

## Backstory

From a little googling, I surmised that the best way to deploy to prod without making manual changes to the conf file each time was to maintain separate conf files and overriding the conf-file-to-use in the procfile

## My Approach

I created two conf files

application.conf -- http://pastebin.com/BaaBuRHR

prod.conf

```
  include "application.conf"
  http.port=${PORT} 
  applyEvolutions.default=true 
  db.default.driver=org.postgresql.Driver 
  db.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
  db.default.user=xxxxxxxxxxx
  db.default.password=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

My Procfile looks like this

```
web: target/start ${JAVA_OPTS} -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/prod.conf
```

When I deploy, my logs say

```
Feb 03 06:34:09 psytools heroku/web.1:  Starting process with command `target/start ${JAVA_OPTS} -Dconfig.file=/conf/prod.conf` 
Feb 03 06:34:10 psytools app/web.1:  Play server process ID is 2 
Feb 03 06:34:11 psytools app/web.1:  [[37minfo[0m] application - Application has started 
Feb 03 06:34:11 psytools app/web.1:  [[37minfo[0m] play - Application started (Prod) 
Feb 03 06:34:11 psytools app/web.1:  [[37minfo[0m] play - Listening for HTTP on port 9000... 
Feb 03 06:34:11 psytools heroku/web.1:  Error R11 (Bad bind) -> Process bound to port 9000, should be 39098 (see environment variable PORT)
```

Clearly, heroku is trying to use the default port 9000 rather than use the PORT env.

My questions are :

1. Is this the correct way to maintain prod/dev environments
2. Why is the port not being read off PORT env variable
3. Previously, when i was just beginning to `Play` :D,

my application.conf had the line

```
 db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://ec2-54#####l0k8?ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.#ssl.NonValidatingFactory"
```

and my proc file was

```
 web: target/start xxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxxxx xxxxx -Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}
```

the DATABASE_URL actually turned out to be just the `postgresql://ec2-54#####l0k8` part. But this still worked which means heroku used the database url from the conf rather than from the proc file..does this mean the proc file overrides do not work?

Comment: You’re specifying an absolute path to your config file – `/opt/conf/prod.conf`, which likely won’t work on Heroku. (In fact it doesn’t look like that file is even in your repo). Can you specify a relative path, e.g. just `prod.conf`, in your `Procfile` where `prof.conf` is in the top level of your app?

Comment: @matt You are right. The path `/opt/conf/prod.conf` was given in the Heroku's documentation somewhere and I presumed that is how it is stored on heroku' side.Nevertheless, when i specify just prod.conf, the database url is being picked correctly but the `${PORT}` is still not being read

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change your Proc file in

> web: target/start ${JAVA_OPTS} -Dconfig.resource=prod.conf

Comment: This partly solves the problem but the port is still not set correctly

Comment: The papertrail logs show that the database URL is being configured correctly in the prod.conf but in the same file Http.Port is not being set correctly??   [prod.conf](http://pastebin.com/U6zfLjU7)

Comment: I finally made it work by adding `-DHttp.Port=${PORT}` in the procfile rather than in the conf file.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you will have one generic config file and use config vars to adjust behavior/settings. You can use foreman and a '.env' file to configure local env vars, and 'heroku config:set ...' for production

See these guides:

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars
- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

Answer (score 0):

I'm always using reversed order and that works:

- in 'main' `application.conf` don't set up the `db.default.url`, `user` and `password` as Heroku does it with `-Ddb.default.url=${DATABASE_URL}`. Always use this file for configuring application for production mode.
- Create file: `conf/local_rustic_bit.conf` include there `application.conf` and put there overriding settings for your local DB, other mailer settings, other debugging rules etc... preferably it should be added to `.gitignore` ie.: `conf/local_*.conf`
- Create `run.sh` (`run.bat` in Windows) file on your local machine and put there command for running play with included 'local' config. Of course you can/should do the same with `start.sh` to test application locally in production mode.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  play -Dconfig.file=/opt/conf/local_rustic.bit.conf "~run 9123"
  ```
- From now you can run your app locally with desired DB settings (via `./run.sh`), and for production, Heroku will be able to run application with its own settings without need to select any additional config.